# How to add collation in an existing element range index in marklogic

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-7

I have already created an element range index in MarkLogic 7 with scalar type `gYear`. I wrote the following script, ran it and successfully created the index,

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
let $newRangeIndexes := (
    <range-element-index xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">
      <scalar-type>gYear</scalar-type>
      <namespace-uri>http://www.dummy.com/namespaces/dummy</namespace-uri>
      <localname>dummyValue</localname>
      <range-value-positions>false</range-value-positions>
    </range-element-index>
)
  let $config := admin:get-configuration()
  let $dbid := xdmp:database()
  let $newConfig :=  admin:database-add-range-element-index($config, $dbid, $newRangeIndexes)
  return
     admin:save-configuration($newConfig)*
```

It does not include a `collation` element as this is not mandatory for the `gYear` scalar type. After creating this index the default value of the element `invalid-values` is `reject`.

Now I have a requirement where I have to update this existing index (I have to modify the value of `invalid-values` to `ignore`). When I am trying to do this I am getting an error due to the absence of the `collation` element. I have found out only one solution which is to delete the index and recreate which is not acceptable in my case.

So I would like to add an empty `collation` element in this existing index first and then I will apply my changes for `invalid-values`. So is there any other way out (except deleting the existing one) to update an existing element range index configuration to add an empty `collation` element?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not creating the XML definition for indexes manually, but using the admin functions to do so. In your case that would have been [admin:database-range-element-index](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-range-element-index).

I would not worry too much about deleting and recreating indexes. If you combine a delete and a add, and save both at the same time, MarkLogic will only apply changes as needed.

To replace an existing definition for a particular element with a different one, you could do:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare namespace db = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $database-id := xdmp:database()

let $existing-index := admin:database-get-range-element-indexes($config, $database-id)[
  db:namespace-uri = "http://www.dummy.com/namespaces/dummy"
    and db:localname = "dummyValue"
]
let $config := admin:database-delete-range-element-index($config, $database-id, $existing-index)

let $config :=  admin:database-add-range-element-index($config, $database-id, admin:database-range-element-index(
  "gYear",
  "http://www.dummy.com/namespaces/dummy",
  "dummyValue",
  (), 
  fn:false(),
  "reject"
))

return
  admin:save-configuration($config)
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is really very helpful information. But I am having issue when I am running the script you provided.                                  What I understood I am getting this error during deletion as I am trying to delete an existing element range index which don't have any collation element  (not even any empty string). Because when I created this index I did not provide any collation element (not even any empty string).

Comment: I am getting the following error,                                                           [1.0-ml] ADMIN-NOSUCHITEM: (err:FOER0000) Range Index does not exist: <range-element-index xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database"> <scalar-type>gYear</scalar-type> <namespace-uri>http://www.dummy.com/namespaces/dummy</namespace-uri> <localname>dummyValue</localname> <range-value-positions>false</range-value-positions> </range-element-index>

Comment: Hi @grtjn, Could you please have a look into this?

Comment: There are alternate ways, but those should be performed with guidance from support. I suggest reaching out to them.

Comment: Thanks @grtjn for your help.